# Gimp perspective warning

Tags: gimp, perspective, error

[image]When I try to use Gimp's perspective tool to change a the selection or image, even slightly, I get this:

> Transformation creates a very large item. 
> Applying the transformation will result in an item that is over 25 times larger than the image.

Why does this happen? Is it supposed to?

How can I fix this, so it doesn't happen?

[image]

Comment: That isn't an error. It's merely a warning. It means that your perspective transform is creating a very large image that extends way beyond the bounds of your canvas. The layer will be much bigger than the canvas. The warning is simply to make you aware of that fact.

Comment: Can't reproduce this problem in "Transform selection" mode, only in "Transform layer" mode. what is your Gimp version? Or can you make a screenshot that shows the perpective tool handles (so just before you apply the transform)? Also why are none of the 15 guide lines showing? Zoomed in too much?

Comment: @BillyKerr How do you not have it create such a large image? I'm only trying to make a minor adjustment. It seems almost like just using perspective in the first place does this. I don't really understand why it needs to be that much larger when I'm only trying to warp a small area of the picture.

Comment: @xenoid I added a screenshot of the before.

Comment: Still can't reproduce. Gimp version? And why are you applying the perspective on the selection mask, and not on the selected pixels of the layer? Also, the transform values are very different between the two shots (original one has the transform flipped over (negative sign at lower right).

Comment: 2.10. I'm planning to fill in the selection after the transform. Not that it matters. When I try to do it with the selected pixels, it does the same things. I probably just moved the handles differently. It happens no matter what.

Comment: Okay, all of a sudden, it's not doing it on the layer mode anymore. I guess I'll fill the selection in first. Unless it starts doing it again.